# Having a css class changing dynamically according to the route path not functioning as expected

Tags: css, laravel, routes

I'd like to include an `active class` in a link when I'm on the following path as copied from my browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products?_token=vcLckxysIra4DARsea0vsfqKQ0LgxzlhLaq4g2oD&look=official
```

In my blade I have the following but it's not working when I'm not on that path.

```
<li class="{{ Request::path() === 'products?look=official' ? 'active' : '' }}">Official Khaki Pants & Blouses</li>
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->input()` or `->query()` from `Request` facade or `request()` helper.

```
request()->query('look');
```

```
<li class="{{ request()->query('look') == 'official' ? 'active' : '' }}">
    Official Khaki Pants & Blouses
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="{{ request()->input('look') == 'official' ? 'active' : '' }}">Official Khaki Pants & Blouses</li>
```